# Replace Node.js with Spark-Java on low-memory devices

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, spark-java

Being less than impressed by `node` (other than that it runs nicely with 16 MB of memory or less) I'm looking to replace [a very simple Node.js app](https://github.com/filebot/filebot-node/tree/master/server-nodejs) with something nicer. [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) (based on jetty) looks very promising.

If I run a *very simple* Spark/Jetty service with `-Xmx16m` (or 32m if need be, using the standard Oracle JVM) will it run fine? Or will I get lots of `OutOfMemoryError` issues? I'd love to use [Spark with Groovy](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/07/17/sparkberry-pi.html) (or Scala) but that's probably gonna explode my max memory expectations.

Has anybody tried this before? Penny for your thoughts?

Comment: One valid alternative is go. Just started to use it, definitely a good alternative to NodeJs. In my case the app will be running on a Raspberry Pi, so I have the same memory issues.

Comment: In my case **go** would be troublesome. I don't wanna deal with platform-specific native code, because the app will need to run on x86/64 and ARMv5678 (and maybe PPC) and having a single works-on-all-platforms distribution package would be very nice. I'm developing an app for Synology NAS.

Comment: Cross compiling with go from any platform to any target is very simple. You can just deliver all binaries you need with every build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no chance that a java app will be able to run with 16mb of heap ram. Not even 32mb you mention.

A minimum I would start with for a java app with embedded  jetty and sparkjava framework is 256mb.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick with node then.